# How to print the last received signal in GDB?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, coredump

when loading a core dump into GDB the reason why it crashed automatically is displayed. For example

> Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.

Is there any way to get the information again? 
The thing is, that I'm writing a script which needs this information. But if the signal is only available after loading the core dump amd I can't access the information later on.

Is there really no command for such an important feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know what the core file name is, you can issue the `target core` command which respecifies the target core file:

```
(gdb) target core core.8577
[New LWP 8577]
Core was generated by `./fault'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x080483d5 in main () at fault.c:10
10      *ptr = '\123';
(gdb)
```

As for the implied question, *what is the `info last signal` command?*, I don't know.  There does not seem to be one.

---

The core file's name can be obtained from the command `info target`:

```
(gdb) info target
Symbols from "/home/wally/.bin/fault".
Local core dump file:
    `/home/wally/.bin/core.8577', file type elf32-i386.
    0x00da1000 - 0x00da2000 is load1
    0x08048000 - 0x08049000 is load2
...
    0xbfe8d000 - 0xbfeaf000 is load14
Local exec file:
    `/home/wally/.bin/fault', file type elf32-i386.
    Entry point: 0x8048300
    0x08048134 - 0x08048147 is .interp
    0x08048148 - 0x08048168 is .note.ABI-tag
    0x08048168 - 0x0804818c is .note.gnu.build-id
    0x0804818c - 0x080481ac is .gnu.hash
    0x080481ac - 0x080481fc is .dynsym
    0x080481fc - 0x08048246 is .dynstr
...
```

Comment: Thanks, so is there a possibility to read the arguments given to the gdb itself or to pass over arguments to my script like
"gdb executable core --batch -x myscript.py [insert arguments here]" 
Because I also found out this possibility but therefor I need to determine the name of the core file which is usually given via arguments to the gdb

Comment: @Uhlo:  The command `info target` shows the executable and core file names, along with quite a bit more information.  Perhaps that will do?

Answer (score 16):

To print the information about the last signal execute

```
p $_siginfo
```

Comment: Thanks for that alternative! It seems that I can only execute this command after or while the program is executed though. Every time I try it with a core dump it gives me the error `Unable to read siginfo`

Comment: that is expected. It is in-memory state of gdb and is not persisted to disk.

Comment: I can print $_siginfo from a core dump file without executed program.